# Call to undefined function money_format()

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy haciendo mi proyecto en php version 7.1.8 en framework laravel pero me sale este error cuando utilizo Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\money_format()
alguien me pueda ayudar

Comment: De donde traes esa función o dónde está declarada?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`money_format`  no funciona en algunos sistemas. Por ejemplo, si estás probando el código en Windows, te dará el error `Undefined`.  [Lo dice el Manual de PHP en una nota](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.money-format.php):

> La función `money_format()` sólo está definida si el sistema tiene
> capacidad `strfmon`. Por ejemplo, Windows no lo hace, así que
> `money_format()` no está definido en Windows.

En las notas de contribución del mismo Manual [hay una función de Rafael M. Salvioni](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.money-format.php#89060)   que puedes implementar, según él funciona en Windows.

O puedes optar por una implementación más simple, dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer.  Por ejemplo, [en esta respuesta de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21508035/5587982) muestran una forma simple de formatear a dólares:

```
function asDollars($value) {
  return '$' . number_format($value, 2);
}
```

Con esos dos puntos de partida, podrás afrontar el problema con tu propia función, adaptada a las necesidades de tu aplicación.